# Javascript remove all empty innerHTML elements children

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, while-loop, innerhtml

`ul` element that has dynamically loaded `li a` children, sometimes the `li a` populate empty innerHTML. How do I remove all of the `li` elements that have an empty `a` child?

**Current** (errors Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null)

```
var stepList = document.querySelector(".parent"),
    listItems = stepList.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
        if (listItems[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML === "") {
            listItems[i].remove();
        }
    }
```

**Starting**

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li>
        <a href="">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Three</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Goal**

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li>
        <a href="">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Three</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Loop through all the LIs, get `innerText`, use `trim()` to remove surrounding whitespace, and check if it's empty. If it is, delete the element.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with your code is when you remove items, children will actually reduce, so you are shifting everything down one index. People typically loop backwards to stop this error.

Perosnally I would just use a [empty pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) selector with querySelectorAll and a forEach loop.

```js
var emptyAnchors = document.querySelectorAll("li > a:empty")
emptyAnchors.forEach(function (a) {
  a.parentNode.remove()
})
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li>
    <a href="">One</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're looping through a list and removing things, it throws the index off. Loop through it backwards instead:

```js
let lis = document.querySelector(".parent").children

for (let i = lis.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (lis[i].firstElementChild.innerHTML === "") {
        lis[i].remove()
    } 
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
    <li><a href="">One</a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
//list of all anchor elements in your HTML DOM
onload = function() {
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    var anchor = anchors[i];
    if(anchor.innerHTML == "") {
      anchor.parentNode.removeChild(anchor); //removes the anchor
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```html
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x"></a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
<a href="x">Something</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

VERY CHEEKY pure-css solution: cause the `a` tags, and not the `li` tags, to be the ones displaying the list-item bullet-points. Then simply apply `display: none` to all empty `a` tags! (Their containing `li` elements will naturally flatten to `height: 0` since they will be `display: block`, and entirely without content.)

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  display: list-item;
}
a:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
    <li>
        <a href="">One</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Two</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Three</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note that css solutions aren't always ideal, because even if things look fine visually, the semantic markup of the page may still be in an undesirable state.